# updating date via C# or JavaScript causes following error

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I have recently discovered that when I update any date in Lightswitch HTML, whether it be in C# or JavaScript, that it causes the application to display this message:

[image]

if i comment out anything that changes the date then this does not appear.. **so my question is has anyone else come across this problem and if so, what is the fix?**

some examples of code that causes the error:

JS - Executed on a custom Save button

```
var today = new Date();
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 0);

if (screen.OrderRequest.changedate == null) {
    screen.OrderRequest.changedate = tomorrow;
}
```

C# executed on either the inserting or updating method

```
partial void OrderRequests_Updating(OrderRequest entity) {
    entity.changedate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

JS - executed in the beforeApplyChanges also causes same error:

```
myapp.OrderScreenView.beforeApplyChanges = function (screen) {

screen.OrderRequest.changedate = Date.now();

};
```

Comment: Extremely odd, I haven't come across it personally however there are a few things you could try: Try changing the sql datatype, and any sql defaults.

Comment: If you give up you could always implement a SQL Trigger or call a stored procedure (messier)

Comment: well a friend has just advised me to update it on the post render of the date and then immediately save it (myapp.activeDataWorkspace.yourdatabaseDate.saveChanges(); and so far its worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that your custom save button is causing the problem.  Any chance you could implement the beforeApplyChanges event and handle any updates there?

Comment: ill give that a go now

Comment: unfortunately no luck with this either... its a very strange issue, it happens in new projects I create aswell, do you ever have this issue?

Comment: I've been on an LS2013 Html project for 8 months now and have never come across it.  It's got me stumped too.

Comment: ill create the scenario in a new project and share a dropbox link

Comment: worked it out... in my SQL Server table DateRequired is just a date, where as changedate is datetime.... it appears that the program does something else to take away the time after, therefore resulting in an additional change taking place....

Comment: Great! I suggested that two days ago. :) It's often the simplest thing.